# Chrome skinny CSS grids mystery gap

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive, css-grid

I've noticed some strange behavior only in Chrome around CSS grids. It seems to be miscalculating the row height when none is specified.

Simple example:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 9.81183%);
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.child:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
.child:nth-of-type(even) {
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 8;
}
```

My understanding is that the default value being used here for the row height is auto, which means the rows should take the height of tallest grid item. But in this fiddle it looks as if there's enough room for the text to wrap onto just one more line than it actually needs: https://jsfiddle.net/kessbethler/wve16ak5/4/

That might not seem like a big deal, but the effect becomes pronounced when using a very narrow layout with a long block of text, as you might for mobile. Chrome shows a huge empty space below this grid container, whereas in Firefox it's exactly the height of its contents, like you'd expect: https://jsfiddle.net/kessbethler/22bmjfnc/6/

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Was happening on 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) on osx, just updated to Chrome 66.0.3359.139 and still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem is `justify-content: space-around` on the container. If you remove it, the Chrome gap disappears. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Yes this is the workaround I ended up using. Unfortunately it means I have to replace all the whitespace with extra grid columns and adjust the grid-column-start and end values for all the grid items, but it works.